# How to prevent cutting off absolute positioned elements and still keep a box-shadow embrace the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

First of all an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/85uqehz5/

The code is just an example, an easier version of my real code. I figured out that I cant't have both: Setting the wrap-div to `overflow: visible` the menu that shows up isn't cut off but the box shadow doesn't embrace the box; With `overflow:auto;`  the box-shadow is working but the menu cut off. How could I solve this? A fixed height would not be an option.

Example Code:

```js
$('#menu').click(function() {
  $('#menu-list').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
#wrap {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#content2 {
  float: left;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
}

#menu-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content">
    Some Content
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
    Some Content
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    Open Menu
    <div id="menu-list" class="hidden">
      <div> bla </div>
      <div> bla </div>
      <div> bla </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple, in your specific case:

1- Remove `overflow: auto;` from `#wrap`

2- Add this to your `CSS`:

```
#wrap:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

This makes the height of `#wrap`'s calculation include the floated element.

If you have multiple uses declare a class like `clearfix` and use it whenever needed.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/85uqehz5/1/

Answer (score 1):

Floats must be cleared: https://jsfiddle.net/85uqehz5/3/

`<div id="wrap" class="clearfix">`

The reason the menu is cut off is because you haven't clear your `float: left` and that is done with such piece of code to the container

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```